# Mindmap-Software with math support?

Tags: mind-mapping

**Is there any Mindmap-Software with *Math* Support?**

- I'd love a feature, that alows me to add some formulas to the nodes or edges.
- I don't care which platform (Mac, Linux, Windows...)
- It can be nonfree too, although a free version is prefered. :-)

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Are you talking about evaluating mathematical expressions (like Mathematica does), or about entering them (like LaTeX or MathML)?

Answer (score 0):

[FreeMind](http://freemind.sf.net) has support for LaTeX-style maths in one version, see [FreeMind SourceForge Wiki - Math](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Math).